# Visual Studio Git pull, merge sync specified path, file name or both are too long

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, git-merge, git-pull

I have a branch where by every time I perform a pull, sync or merge i get this error in Visual Studio 2017. "The specified path, file name or both are too long. The full qualified filename must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters."

This error message seems a bit too vague as it doesn't pin point where the problem is. Is it the path name that is too long, file name or the directory name.

To get around this I have to perform the actions through gitbash.

How can i resolve this issue?

Attache dis the screenshot of the error.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The key here is to find your solution's .git folder, which will be in the root of your Visual Studio solution. Right-click your solution entry in Solution Explorer and choose Open Folder in File Explorer. You will see the .git folder there:

[image: Solution's .git folder in File Explorer]

Take note of the path that leads to this .git folder. Chances are that it's not in the root of the drive but is instead a folder or several folders down from the root. Whoever created the repository had located their solution closer to the root and never exceeded the path limit you're exceeding.

The solution is to do a Git pull to a folder location that's as close to the root as possible. Try creating a folder such as "C:\MyWork" (or something like that) and pull to that folder. You very likely will get past this error. Once you do, you can drill down and inspect the deepest and longest folder paths within your solution structure. If you can identify unnecessarily long or deeply nested folders, you can shorten them and check those changes back to the repo so that others can pull to their own root folders without worrying about path lengths.

Comment: Facing similar issue in VS2019. The path is 55 characters long only!

Comment: That doesn't sound right to me--what exactly have you determined has a 55 character limit?

Comment: The root folder of my project, where the .git folder is stored. It is two folders inside the C drive and the total character count till that is 55.

Comment: Right. But 55 characters isn't a "limit". The limit comes from adding that 55 to the longest path that's under that .git folder level. It might seem like "only" 55 characters, but if your longest path under that is, say, 200 characters long, then adding that to 55 exceeds the actual limit. As inconvenient as it is, you really must create a short path to the root. If that cannot be on your C drive then create a partition on that drive or on another device so that you can start with X:\ and place the folder closer to the root.